# PHP is just getting the first character from string

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.4

I have some data in an associative array and when I pass each element of the array to a variable, it only gets the first character of the string.

For example:

```json
array (size=5)
  'data' => 
    array (size=14)
      'number' => string '321335' (length=6)
      'text' => string 'abcde' (length=5)
```

```php
$number = $commentData['data']['number'];
$text = $commentData['data']['text'];

echo $text;
// Output: a
echo $number;
// Output: 3
```

I expected to return all string on variable. I tried:

```php
echo $commentData['data']['number'];
// Output: a
echo $commentData['data']['text'];
// Output: 3
```

Comment: Can you show the result of `var_dump($commentData);`?

Comment: Better still, show us `var_export($commentData);` instead, then the output will be re-usable as PHP code, so we can test it easily and make examples / answers without having to re-key it. Thanks. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php . Based on what you've shown so far, we don't appear to have a [mre] of the issue. What you are stating, does not seem to be possible, based on the (admittedly limited) data provided.